# ConcurrencyCheck attribute to property not updating Column value in database while using EF core Bulk extension

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework, ef-core-2.0

Class: RequestStatus Column is annoted  for ConcurrencyCheck

```
public class Entity 
{  
    public string TicketNumber { get; set; }

    [ConcurrencyCheck]
    public string RequestStatus { get; set; }

    //Other Properties here
}
```

I am using BulkInsertUpdate EF core method to update main entity and its child entites as:

```
protected async Task BulkUpdate(Entity[]] entities, User user)
{
    string sessionGUID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    Entity entity = entities.Where(f => f.isMainEntity == true).First();

    // validations
    if (entities.Any(f =>!string.IsNullOrEmpty(f.flag?.Trim()))
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }

     // Main Entity
    entity.ReviewerId = user.UserId;
    entity.status = Entity.status.Value ? true : false;

    if (Entity.status.Value)
    {
        if (true)
        {
            await this.Queue(sessionGUID)
        }

        entity.RequestStatus = "Approve"
    }

    // Related Entities
    foreach (Entity relatedEntity in entities.Where(f => f.isMainEntity.Value != true))
    {

       //Update related Entities properties
    }

    await this.Uow.Entity.BulkInsertOrUpdate(entities);
}
```

> Sometimes value for **RequestStatus** column is not getting updated in DB. But other column values gets updated everytime.

I am using EF core Bulk extension for bulk update which internally has savechanges method.

[GitHub URL](https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions).

Comment: Is an exception thrown? What database are you using?

Comment: `ConcurrencyCheck` means that the field should be used for concurrency checking, not that EF will set any specific value to it. If your code doesn't change that value, it won't be changed in the database.

Comment: Where *do* you save the data? There's no `SaveChanges` in the code posted here. There's a call to `this.Uow.Entity.BulkInsertOrUpdate(entities)` whatever that is, and a lot of hints to other modifications.

Comment: @mjwills No exception is thrown. SQL DB

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Code is changing the value to "Approve"

Comment: @mjwills yes Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: @SagarK and where do you *save* the changes? How do you know `BulkInsertOrUpdate` didn't throw, or swallowed the error with a `catch{}`? You are asking people to guess about your code. Post a *minimal* example that actually reproduces the problem. In any case, you aren't asking about `ConcurrencyCheck`, you are asking why a changed value wasn't saved in the database

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am using EFCore.BulkExtensions for bulk updates https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions. 
Parent method has try catch and app-insight is also enabled. there is no any exception and as i said it is happening intermittently